# SQL Server not checking for expired passwords

Tags: sql-server-2005, password

We are using SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 with Windows Authentication where access is granted to members of a specific domain group.  Clients are VB6/ADO applications that connect via an ODBC System DSN.

I noticed recently that users are being granted access to SQL Server despite their password having expired.  For example, if a user's password expires at midday on a given work-day they are rightly allowed to login to their machine first thing in the morning but if they attempt to login to SQL Server (by running the client application) in the afternoon I would expect SQL Server to reject the connection.  This is not what we're seeing in practise though, the connection is still being allowed.  Other services such as Exchange reject connections under the same circumstances.

Is SQL Server caching credentials?  Is there a way to force SQL Server to check for password expiration?  Why would SQL Server behave differently than, for example, Exchange?

Comment: Yes, interactive users can use cached credentials (see some background [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18787/connecting-to-sql-server-using-cached-credentials)). I don't know if there is any exposed way to change this behavior.